# Joining three mysql tables - inner join

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have three tables :

first table :

tractions :

```
1   id  
2   price   
3   date    
4   user_id 
5   ip  
6   code    
7   succ    
8   admin_seen  
9   user_seen   
10  coupon_id
11  cradit_start_date
12  cradit_end_date
13  shop_id
```

second table :

coupons :

```
1   id  
2   title   
3   slider_title    
4   short_title 
5   pic 
6   text    
7   attrs   
8   jest    
9   terms_of_use    
10  how_to_use
```

Third table :

shops :

```
1   id
2   title   
3   address 
4   phone
```

now, I would like to get these values depending on id tractions:

```
tractions.price ,tractions.cradit_start_date,tractions.cradit_end_date,
    shops.address,coupons.terms_of_use,coupons.attrs
```

I wrote this function but it returns null value :

```
function getContentACopounForQRReader($id){

    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
    $result_qr  =   mysql_query("select tractions.price ,tractions.cradit_start_date,tractions.cradit_end_date,
    shops.address,coupons.terms_of_use,coupons.attrs
    from tractions
    INNER JOIN shops ON shops.id = tractions.shop_id
    INNER JOIN coupons ON coupons.id = tractions.coupon_id
    where tractions.id = $id");

    $row = mysql_fetch_object($result_qr);

    $marr = array('price'=>$row->price);

    return $marr ;

}
```

(I know that I must use mysqli or PDO)

Comment: It appears you `tractions` table doesn't have a `shop_id`, or did you just miss this out when typing out the structure?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. I updated my question.

Comment: Did you check if the function is receiving the right id ?

Comment: yes, I send an id value from cellphone (android).

Comment: Doesn't seem like there's anything wrong with your query to me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d332e/1

Comment: Echo the id in the function and after that try to run the query with the id and check if mysql give you back an error.

Comment: Are you sure that your DB has needed data and after join query returned result? try to hardcode data to tables and run again